# Reluctant quatnifier not working in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

If the following function is called in node v0.10.26:

```
    function parseAndLog(constraint) {
        var constraintRegex = /\s*(.*?)\s*(<=|==|>=|[GL]?EQ)\s*(.*?)\s*(!required|!strong|!medium|!weak)?/;
        console.log(constraintRegex.exec(constraint));
    }
```

with the input:

```
"thumb.top == group.top + 20"
```

I expected that the following would be returned as substring matches (as happens when a similar function is called in Java)

```
thumb.top 
==
group.top + 20
```

But only the following is returned

```
thumb.top 
==
```

I hoped that `"group.intrinsicHeight == preamble.bottom !medium"` would yeild

```
group.intrinsicHeight
==
preamble.bottom
!medium
```

but only get the following

```
group.intrinsicHeight
==
```

I suspect the issue is something to do with the `(.*?)` group. I think this is known as a reluctant quantifier. Is it even supported by Javascript? If not, is there a workaround? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because it's not greedy, the `*?` quantifier is going to start off by seeing whether it matches *nothing*. In your case, that's what happens for the second group.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use start and end anchors.

```
^\s*(.*?)\s*(<=|==|>=|[GL]?EQ)\s*(.*?)\s*(!required|!strong|!medium|!weak)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nW8vL6/1)

```
String str = "thumb.top == group.top + 20\n" + 
             "group.intrinsicHeight == preamble.bottom !medium";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\s*(.*?)\\s*(<=|==|>=|[GL]?EQ)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(!required|!strong|!medium|!weak)?$").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
    if(m.group(1) != null)  { System.out.println(m.group(1)); }
    if(m.group(1) != null)  { System.out.println(m.group(2)); }
    if(m.group(1) != null)  { System.out.println(m.group(3));  }
    if(m.group(1) != null)  { System.out.println(m.group(4)); }
}
```

Because you described all the patterns except `(<=|==|>=|[GL]?EQ)` to repeat zero or more times. So it don't care about that there is a following `(!required|!strong|!medium|!weak)` or not, since you made this pattern as optional. By adding the start and end anchors, it ensures that the optional `(!required|!strong|!medium|!weak)` is followed by end of the line anchor. So regex engine tries to match upto the line end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's in Java! The expression already works in Java. I'm looking for a solution in Javascript.

Comment: Your suggestion works though under Javascript. Do you know why?

Comment: But it works without the start and end anchors in Java.

Comment: i think , in java you did use the matches method. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, in java it looks like this:   ```private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(.*?)\\s*(<=|==|>=|[GL]?EQ)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(!(required|strong|medium|weak))?");```

Comment: because matches method tries to match the whole input string. I won't need anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Adding start and end anchors made the regular expression behave as desired in Javascript

e.g. `/^\s*(.*?)\s*(<=|==|>=|[GL]?EQ)\s*(.*?)\s*(!(required|strong|medium|weak))?$/;`

Thanks to @avinash-raj for the suggestion.

If anybody could offer an explanation as to why this works and if the `(.*?)`group is in fact a "reluctant quantifier", I'd be grateful.

Comment: I explained the reason.